# Discord.js/Mongodb Get message author tag

Tags: node.js, mongodb, discord.js

At the moment I am trying to log the user's tag who sent a message using mongodb, but I can't seem to get my head around getting the tag itself:

```
await client.on('message', id => {

    Config.findOne({
        Author_Tag: id
    }, (err, guild) => {
        if (err) console.error(err);

        if (!guild) {
            const newConfig = new Config({
                Author_Tag: id,
            });

            return newConfig.save()
        }
        })
    }
```

I realize that `message.author.id` is required, but I don't know where it would go.

Right now, when someone executes a command, the database logs the message of the bot and the user, not the tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha I figured it out:

```js
await client.on("message", (message) => {
  Config.findOne(
    {
      Author_Tag: message.author.tag,
    },
    (err, guild) => {
      if (err) console.error(err);

      if (!guild) {
        const newConfig = new Config({
          Author_Tag: message.author.tag,
        });

        return newConfig.save();
      }
    }
  );
});
```

I changed `id` to `message.author.tag`

Comment: You can press the green tick near your Question to accept it as the approved Question

Comment: I know but I have to wait 2 days to do that